# Using a sample list as a template for sampling from a larger list without wraparound

Tags: r, sampling

If I have a vector of letters:

```
> all <- letters
> all
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

and then I define a reference sample from letters as follows:

```
> refSample <- c("j","l","m","s")
```

in which the spacing between elements is 2 (1st to 2nd), 1 (2nd to 3rd) and 6 (3rd to 4th), how can I then select *n* samples from `all` that have identical, non-wrap-around spacing between its elements to `refSample`? For example, `"a","c","d","j"` and `"q" "s" "t" "z"` would be valid samples, but `"a","c","d","k"` and `"r" "t" "u" "a"`  would not. The former has an index difference of 7 (rather than 6) between the 3rd and last element, whereas the latter has the correct spacing but wraps around.

Second, how can I parameterise this, so that whatever `refSample` is used, I can use the spacing of that as a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way --

```
all <- letters                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
refSample <- c("j","l","m","s")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               


pick_matches <- function(n, ref, full) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  iref <- match(ref,full)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  spaces <- diff(iref)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  tot_space <- sum(spaces)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  max_start <- length(full)  - tot_space                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  starts <- sample(1:max_start, n, replace = TRUE)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  return( sapply( starts, function(s) full[ cumsum(c(s, spaces)) ] ) )                                                                                                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

> set.seed(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
> pick_matches(5, refSample, all) # each COLUMN is a desired sample vector                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [1,] "e"  "g"  "j"  "p"  "d"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [2,] "g"  "i"  "l"  "r"  "f"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [3,] "h"  "j"  "m"  "s"  "g"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 [4,] "n"  "p"  "s"  "y"  "m"
```